# Try and catch not working on flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, try-catch

I have tried try and catch on my vs code but the catch function does not handle the error and I have also tried the same code on dartpad website but on the website the catch function is working please look into my code:
[image]

I tried to use try and catch function and I was expecting to handle the error with catch function but the catch function is not handling the error

Comment: If you post your code here we can better help you

Comment: I believe this is related https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/33427

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this instead?

```
throw Exception('Page not found');
```

I believe you are trying to throw a string as an exception.

Comment: I am using firebase authentication and there i need to use try and catch but the try and catch was not working, therefore to see what's the matter I wrote a simple try catch func as you can see above but this simple code is also not running, the catch func is not catching the error, but when I tried the exact same code in dartpad it worked beautifully